# if ternario php

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un metodo o function donde actualizo y creo si existe un valor

```
public function createupdatepayment(PaymentTypeFormRequest $request)
    {
        $rut = Auth::user()->rut;
        
        $paymentcondition = PendingDocument::updateOrCreate(
            ['docentry'     => $request->DocEntry],
            ['tipodecobro'  => $request->tipodecobro,
            'banco'         => $request->banco
            ]
        );
       
        return view('frontend.billing.pending');
}
```

Se va a dar el caso en el que si tengo un tipo cobro que trae como valor confirming me guarde el valor del banco, de lo contrario si es distinto me almacene un NUll en el campo de la tabla

`'banco' => $request->banco`

se me ocurre algo asi pero me enredo en como paso los valores, la idea es que se almacene el banco que viene solo si llega Confirming, de lo contrario se alamacene un valor null

`'banco' => $request->tipodecobro ? Confirming ($request->banco) : null,`

Este es mi fomulario edit en el front desde donde viene el confirming en un value del option

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route("frontend.billing.update")}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DocEntry" id="DocEntry" value="{{ request()->DocEntry }}" hidden>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required" for="tipodecobro">Cambiar tipo de cobro</label>                
                <select class="form-control select2" name="tipodecobro" id="tipodecobro" required>                   
                        <option value="Vencimiento en 30 días">Vencimiento en 30 días</option>                
                        <option value="Factoring" id="topic">Factoring</option>
                        <option value="Confirming">Confirming</option>
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('name'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group d-none" id="bancos">
                <label class="required" for="banco">Seleccione un banco</label>                
                <select class="form-control select2" name="banco" id="banco">
                    <option value="">Seleccione un Banco</option>
                    @foreach($bancos as $banco)
                        <option value="{{$banco->name}}">{{$banco->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('name'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div> 

            <div class="form-group d-flex mt-5">
            <a href="{{route('frontend.billing.pending')}}" class="btn button button--danger font-weight-bold mr-auto">
             Cancelar
         </a>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn button button--primary button--large font-weight-bold" href="{{route('frontend.billing.pending')}}">
</div>
@csrf
</form>
```

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el dato a evaluar, ¿es este `$request->tipodecobro` o es este: `Confirming ($request->banco)`?

Comment: Recuerda siempre [edit] la pregunta antes que añadir no-respuestas

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar: ¿cuál es el dato a evaluar? ni siquiera eso queda claro en tu pregunta.

Comment: el error esta en como recuperar el dato primero que nada y luego como haces la comparacion.

Comment: el valor a revisar es el Confirming, es un valor que viene desde un selecp option es un value del option, no se si se entiende?

Comment: ok pero entonces confirming tiene que ser igual a que??? y como se llama en el form confirming??

Comment: ```$request->tipodecobro ? Confirming```
aqui el ```$request->tipocobro``` tiene que ser igual a ```Confirming```, de serlo que almacene un valor que viene del input, de no serlo que inserte o almacene un ```null```

Comment: $request->tipodecobro ? $request->confirming; // tienes dos datos en el mismo formulario????

Comment: A ver: ¿`Confirming ($request->banco)` devuelve un valor, es eso? Si es eso, puedes asignar el valor así simplemente: `'banco'         => Confirming ($request->banco) ?? null`, pero, el error dice que `Confirming` no está definida, por tanto, me parece que con esto basta: **`'banco'  => $request->banco ?? null`**, aquí no hemos usado un ternario, sino un operador llamado *fusión de null* (disponible desde PHP 7+).

Comment: actualice mi comentario, que pase a presionar enter... como asi 2 datos en el mismo formulario?

Comment: Segun tus comentarios, pregunta, etc: tienes un campo que se llama `tipodecobro`  en tu formulario por eso lo llamas asi: `$request->tipodecobro;` luego dices que tienes un select que se llama `comfirming` entonces para usarlo tambien necesitas llamarlo como: `$request->comfirming` por eso te pregunte si tienes esos dos campos en tu formulario... si hay algun dato que traes de otra parte como una base de datos tienes que aclararlo porque tu pregunta le falta informacion y va a recibir votos negativos y sera cerrada.

Comment: Otra cosa que tambien veo ... tienes varias preguntas con respuestas pero no veo que las marques como solucionadas... trata de hacerlo.

Comment: He actualizado mi post con el detalle que me faltaba para dar a entender mas claramente el problema, crei que habia explicado la parte del select... por otra parte si hay preguntas que no marco como solucionada es porque precisamente no las logre solucionar, si elimino los post me penalizan en la plataforma...

Comment: Confirming es un literal ... no es un metodo, no es un campo, no es un select... me parece extraños que estes programando en php y no veas el error que supone utilizar `Confirming()` o `Confirming`

Comment: ya hice los cambios en mi respuesta

Comment: La plataforma no penaliza por borrar publicaciones. Las mismas, se toman en cuenta para los calculos, pero no penalizan ni mas ni menos. Si pudiste resolverlas vos mismo, seria buenisimo que agregues las respuestas y las aceptes!

Comment: En algunos casos pude resolver y puse las respuestas, en otras no hay ni comentarios, puras vistas, creo que habia una a la que respondi y despues de varios dias deja marcar como correcta, por ahi alguna se me puede haber pasado el marcarla como resuelta, ahora en el stackoverflow ingles si me banearon, por eso les digo... de todas formas gracias por los tips y detalles...

Comment: la plataforma te penaliza si haces muchas publicaciones y tienen votos negativos, son mal recibidas... lo ideal es editarlas y arreglarlas para que sean re-abiertas y resivas respuestas de las mismas, hay un limite semana, mensual , trimestral , semestral y anual para hacer preguntas desde una cuenta que relativamente hace malas preguntas y no aportan al sitio... de esa forma es que se penaliza... tambien pase por el baneo del sitio en ingles.

Comment: @TranceCode responde mi respuesta tu pregunta?

Comment: hasta donde parece si lo estoy resolviendo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

las operaciones ternarias deben ir entre parentesis y cuando comparas datos de un formulario tienes que llamarlos como miembros del request.

cuando accedes a los input/miembros se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
$request->tipodecobro; //valida que sea el nombre correcto del campo.
```

Entonces la evaluacion quedaria de la siguiente forma, valor del select vs un Literal (cadena):

```
$banco = ($request->tipodecobro == 'Confirming') ? $request->banco : null;
```

luego en tu array:

```
'banco' => $banco,
```

***nota:*** no recomiendo hacer analisis ternarios dentro de la construccion de los arrays u objetos... pueden liarla cuando vas a realizar un debug.

otro dato importante para que hagas debug y validaciones paso a paso puedes usar `dd()`:

```
dd( request()->all() );
```

***Adicional como se expresan las comparaciones ternarias:***

```php
$variable //variable en donde guardar los datos
            = //signo de asignacion de datos
                ( //signo de apertura de analisis
                    $foo //variable a realizarle el analisis  
                        == //operador logico
                            'Confirming' //dato esperado o de comparacion
                                ) //signo de cierre del analisis
                                    ? //operador ternario
                                        'Es igual' //primer valor para el resultado cierto
                                            : //separador ternario
                                                'No es Igual' //segundo valor para el resultado falso
                                                    ; //Finalizacion de linea de codigo.
```

***Operacion ternaria en una linea como queda:***

```
$variable = ($foo == 'Confirming') ? 'Es igual' : 'No es Igual';
```

***Operacion ternaria en vaerias linea como queda:***

```
$variable = ($foo == 'Confirming') ? 
    'Es igual' : 
    'No es Igual';
```

***Tambien soporta anidar 2 o más operaciones ternarias:***

```
$variable = ($foo == 'Confirming') ? 
    'Es igual 1' : 
    ($foo == 'Divided') ?
        'Es igual 2' :
        'No es Igual a Ninguno';
```

***Nota:*** Pero en este punto ya yo recomendaria usar un `witch`

Answer (score 2):

Si Confirming es una función que devuelve el tipo de cobro, la sentencia sería así

```
'banco' => $request->tipodecobro == Confirming ($request->banco) ? $request->banco : null
```

El primer campo del operador ternario es la condición, el segundo es la acción si la condición es cierta y el tercero es la acción si la condición es falsa

Comment: Gracias amigo, he respondido, el error que me retorna y es que parece que se me fue explicar que confirming es un valor que viene desde un select, es un value dinamico...