# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "elseif"

Tags: php, condiciones, operador

estoy en mi codigo cuando de repente intento entrar en un menu y me lanza el error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "elseif"

alguien que me ayude por favor he intentado solucionarlo pero no hallo como, este es el codigo:

```
function page_require_level($require_level){
     global $session;
     $current_user = current_user();
     $login_level = find_by_groupLevel($current_user['nivel_usuario']);

     //  si el usuario no inicia sesión
     if (!$session->isUserLoggedIn(true)):
            $session->msg('d','Por favor Iniciar sesión...');
            redirect('index.php', false);


      // si el estado del grupo está 
      if (is_array($login_level)) {
        elseif($login_level['grupo_estatus'] === '0'): ** AQUI ES EL ERROR**
          $session->msg('d','Este nivel de usuario esta inactivo!');
          redirect('home.php',false);
      }
    }
```

Comment: No se puede anidar un `else` sin su correspondiente `if`. Al abrir una llave pasas a otro ámbito de bloque, dentro del mismo no existe nigún `if` que haga pareja con el `eseif`. Se podría arreglar quitando solo el `else` y dejándolo como `if`normal. Claro, como no conocemos el contexto de ese código, puede que dejen de funcionar otras cosas.

Comment: @aeportugal estoy casi seguro que se comio los bracket o intentava hacer algun analisis ternario por que hay le vi los `:` colados ... ya le di una respuesta para que resuelva...

Answer (score 0):

como tu mismo lo dices en esta linea:

```
elseif($login_level['grupo_estatus'] === '0'): ** AQUI ES EL ERROR**
```

debe de ser

```
}elseif($login_level['grupo_estatus'] === '0'){
```

incluso no es el unico error no se por que estas usando un operador `:` en tu codigo cuando o que pretendes... tu codigo final deberia lucir asi:

```php
function page_require_level($require_level)
{
    global $session;
    $current_user = current_user();
    $login_level = find_by_groupLevel($current_user['nivel_usuario']);

    //  si el usuario no inicia sesión
    if (!$session->isUserLoggedIn(true)){

        $session->msg('d','Por favor Iniciar sesión...');
        redirect('index.php', false);

    }


    // si el estado del grupo está 
    if (is_array($login_level)) {

        //esto lo tienes vacio no se porque...

    } elseif($login_level['grupo_estatus'] === '0') {

        $session->msg('d','Este nivel de usuario esta inactivo!');
        redirect('home.php',false);

    }
}
```

Si estas implementando algun tipo de analisis ternario entonces tendrias que hacerlo como lo describo en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/552261/46896